# (#100) The Action Type <type:action>is not approved, so app <app-id>can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am in development mode of a facebook app. I have two users for my app: myself as admin and other as tester. I am using GRAPH API explorer to publish a sample custom action. It is always giving following error for both users. I have made sure that I use right permissions and pass right parameters.

```
{  "error": {    "message": "(#100) The Action Type searchmates:Need is not approved, so app <appid> can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User <userid> is not one of those roles.",     "type": "OAuthException",     "code": 100  }}
```

I raised a bug also on facebook: [Defect raised](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/171332866318848). So far no luck. Please help how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a facebook bug, which I am not so sure of, as I never faced this with default or custom action, you have to nail it down by narrowing possibilities.

1. Can it be a valid access token error?
2. Did you place `fb:admins` in your meta tag?
3. Is there any malformed (500 error) url that facebook can't see?

etc.

Comment: still no luck in any of above:(